# calculate the percentage of users from CTE

Tags: postgresql

I've 2 CTE. The first counts the number of users. The second does the same. It is necessary to calculate the percentage ratio between them.

Prompt how it can be done?

```
WITH count AS ( SELECT user_id
                        from users u
                          where u.status = 'Over'),
users as (Select user_id
                from users u
                  where u.status LIKE 'LR'
                  and user_id IN (select * from count))
Select COUNT(*) From users


WITH count AS ( SELECT user_id
                        from users u
                          where u.description = 'Track'),
users as (Select user_id
                from from users u
                  where u.status NOT LIKE 'LR'
                  and user_id IN (select * from count))
Select COUNT(*) From users
```

Comment: the ratio between Over and Track?

Comment: Between cte users and count. And also between track and over. But the main thing to count between users cte and count cte. I think, I will be able to count between track and over if you set me an example between count and users. In any couple of CTE

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without CTE, just simple select with 2 counts:

```
SELECT count( CASE WHEN description = 'Over' AND status LIKE 'LR' THEN 1 END )
       /
       count( CASE WHEN description = 'Track' AND status NOT LIKE 'LR' THEN 1 END )    
       As Ratio
FROM users
```

Comment: Yeah, and `NOT LIKE 'LR'` is simply `<> 'LR'`

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes, you can just do one bigger CTE:

```
WITH count_1 AS 
( 
  SELECT user_id
  FROM users u
  WHERE u.status = 'Over'
),
users_1 AS 
(
  SELECT user_id
  FROM   users u
  WHERE  u.status LIKE 'LR'
        AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM count_1)
),
count_2 AS 
(   
  SELECT user_id
  FROM users u
  WHERE u.description = 'Track'
),
users_2 AS 
(
  SELECT  user_id
  FROM users u
  WHERE u.status NOT LIKE 'LR'
                  AND user_id IN (select user_id from count_2)
)
SELECT
  CAST( (SELECT count(*) FROM users_1) AS FLOAT) / 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM users_2) AS ratio
```

NOTE 1: The query doesn't make any sense, so I guess there is some misspelling, or some columns messed up. The `count_1` will choose users with a status = 'Over', the `users_1` will choose the ones which have also a status = 'LR' (the result is already ZERO).

NOTE 2: You wouldn't make queries this way... The following query means exactly the same, and is much simpler (and faster):

```
WITH 
count_1 AS 
( 
  SELECT count(user_id) AS c
  FROM   users u
  WHERE      u.description = 'Over'
         AND u.status = 'LR' 
),
count_2 AS 
(   
  SELECT count(user_id) AS c
  FROM   users u
  WHERE      u.description = 'Track'
         AND u.status <> 'LR'
)
SELECT
    (count_1.c + 0.0) / count_2.c AS ratio
FROM
    count_1, count_2 ;
```

Comment: Thank you! But I think this statment SELECT
  CAST( (SELECT count(*) FROM users_1) AS FLOAT) / 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM users_2) AS ratio  is not true for percent(  In first CTE I've 9361 rows, in second 1855 rows but result is 5 percent(

Comment: Percent for this results is 19,8 but result is 5( @joanolo

Comment: For percent, you need to *100.0

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version:

```
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE description = 'Over' AND status LIKE 'LR')
       /
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE description = 'Track' AND status NOT LIKE 'LR')    
       As Ratio
FROM users
```